# Listbox duplicate values

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

**SOLVED**

```
    protected void ButtonAddDevTools_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var vItem in ListBoxDevTools.Items)
        {
            if (ValueAlreadyInListDevTools(vItem))
                return;
        }


        ListBoxDevTools.Items.Add(
            new ListItem(
                DropDownListDevTools.SelectedItem.ToString() + " - " +
                RadioButtonListDevTools.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                DropDownListDevTools.SelectedValue));
    }

    private bool ValueAlreadyInListDevTools(object vItem)
    {
        var strCurrent = DropDownListDevTools.SelectedItem.ToString() + " - " +
                         RadioButtonListDevTools.SelectedItem.ToString();

        return strCurrent == vItem.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your code, I see that when the item is not in ListBoxDatabases, you add a new ListItem. This is not the same object as the DropDownListDB.SelectedItem (you create a new different object) So everytime you get there, you'll just add a new entry.

Comment: So is `(ListBoxDatabases.Items.Contains(DropDownListDB.SelectedItem) == false)` better?